# How to merge list of maps to one map in Kotlin?

Tags: java, dictionary, kotlin, enums

I have a `List<Map<Enum, Set<String>>>` and I need to get a `Map<Enum, Set<String>>`

For example, I have:

```
listOf(mapOf(Enum.First to setOf("one", "two", "three")),
 mapOf(Enum.Second to setOf("four", "five", "six")))
```

I need:

```
mapOf(Enum.First to setOf("one", "two", "three"), Enum.Second to setOf("four", "five", "six"))
```

Comment: What if the list has two maps that both has the key `Enum.First`? Do you want to merge the sets?

Answer (score 1):

This function flattens a list of maps to a single map. Note that if there are any duplicate keys, only the value for the last occurrence of the key will be present.

```
fun <K, V> flatten(list: List<Map<K, V>>): Map<K, V> =
    mutableMapOf<K, V>().apply {
        for (innerMap in list) putAll(innerMap)
    }
```

Example:

```
enum class Enum { First, Second }

fun main() {
    val list = listOf(
        mapOf(Enum.First to setOf("one", "two", "three")),
        mapOf(Enum.Second to setOf("four", "five", "six"))
    )
    val map = flatten(list)
    println(map)
}
```

Output:

```
{First=[one, two, three], Second=[four, five, six]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
fun getMapOf(listOfMaps: List<Map<Enum, Set<String>>>): Map<Enum, Set<String>> {
    return listOfMaps
        .flatMap { map -> map.entries }
        .associate(Map.Entry<Enum, Set<String>>::toPair)

}
```

Comment: Worth nothing that this will make a `Pair` for every `Map.Entry` before putting them in the new map. Maybe `associate { it.toPair() }` would make that clearer?

Comment: Thanks, it's more concise now.

Comment: More concise, but I wanted to point out this creates N+1 extra objects: One extra list, and N pairs. My answer creates 0 extra objects.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip I think [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68317523/1431750) also has the same overhead - creating a Pair for each Entry. Don't know why Kotlin doesn't allow/have the feature to convert a list of same-typed-MapEntries to a Map with those Entries.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip Yes, I agree with you. It's just another solution. Thanks for pointing to this.

Comment: @aneroid I was wondering about the lack of a `Map.Entry` -> `Map` function too. I wonder if it's been proposed? It might be something they'd consider adding. There are functions for `List<Int>` -> `IntArray` etc., so `List<Map.Entry>` -> `Map` seems fair game.

Comment: There is an issue raised, [KT-37942](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-37942), but it's currently shelved because they don't see a realistic situation where you'd need to do this conversion.

Comment: Nice find. I realised that collections.associate and .associateBy kinda provide this functionality, which I just added to my answer.

Comment: This will not merge the sets, will simply discard items when there's a key in common

Answer (score 1):

My initial approach was [similar to Adam Millerchip's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68315865/1431750) (mutableMap and putAll). That works better when each map in the list contains multiple entries.

However, for the OP's specific case where there's **just one Entry per Map** in the list, the following solution is convenient:

```kotlin
val map = list.map { it.entries.first().toPair() }.toMap()
```

That iterates over the list and each `Map` uses `entries.first()` to get its one and only `Entry` and make it a `Pair`. The resulting list of `Pair`s is then converted into a `Map`.

Alternative, with [Associate](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-transformations.html#associate) - using [**`associate(transform -> Pair)`**](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate.html) by providing a lambda which returns a `Pair(key, value)`.

```kotlin
val map = list.associate { it.entries.first().toPair() }
```

And since OP hasn't specified what to do with Maps having the same key, *"if there are any duplicate keys, only the value for the last occurrence of the key will be present."*

Example function of the first option:

```kotlin
fun <K, V> singleEntryMapListToMap(list: List<Map<K, V>>) =
    list.map {
        it.entries.first().toPair()
    }.toMap()
```

Output:

```
{First=[one, two, three], Second=[four, five, six]}
```

Comment: `it.entries` is possibly clearer than `it.asSequence()`?

Comment: @AdamMillerchip Doh! Yeah, that's much cleaner and clearer. Updated. And yes, I see from history that you used it in an earlier version of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is a specific optimized `Map` implementation to hold enum keys: [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html).

Unfortunately, there are no convenient functions in Kotlin stdlib for `EnumMap` creation (like for other `Map` implementations), so you may define your own (thanks to [@Adam Millerchip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1225617/adam-millerchip) for the idea):

```kotlin
inline fun <reified K : kotlin.Enum<K>, V> enumMapOf() = EnumMap<K, V>(K::class.java)
inline fun <reified K : kotlin.Enum<K>, V> enumMapOf(vararg pairs: Pair<K, V>) = pairs.toMap(EnumMap(K::class.java))
```

Secondly, there could be different strategies to mitigate the situation when there are two maps in the original list with the same key (and different values):

```kotlin
val list = listOf(
    mapOf(Enum.First to setOf("one", "two", "three")),
    mapOf(Enum.Second to setOf("four", "five", "six")),
    mapOf(Enum.First to setOf("four", "five", "six"))
)
```

The simple strategy is "latest wins":

```kotlin
val res = list.fold(enumMapOf<Enum, Set<String>>()) { acc, map ->
    acc.apply { putAll(map) }
}
println(res) // {First=[four, five, six], Second=[four, five, six]}
```

Another approach is "merge values":

```kotlin
val resMerged = list.fold(enumMapOf<Enum, Set<String>>()) { acc, map ->
    map.forEach { (k, v) -> acc.merge(k, v) { old, new -> old.union(new) } }
    acc
}
println(resMerged) // {First=[one, two, three, four, five, six], Second=[four, five, six]}
```

For convenience, you may define an auxiliary extension method for merging maps (and use `union` with infix call):

```
fun <K, V : Any> MutableMap<K, V>.merge(map: Map<K, V>, remappingFunction: (V, V) -> V) {
    map.forEach { (k, v) -> this@merge.merge(k, v, remappingFunction) }
}

val resMerged = list.fold(enumMapOf<Enum, Set<String>>()) { acc, map ->
    acc.apply { merge(map) { old, new -> old union new } }
}
println(resMerged) // {First=[one, two, three, four, five, six], Second=[four, five, six]}
```

Comment:  +1 Was about to ask what the `Enum::class.java` in the EnumMap constructor was but docs answered: _"Creates an empty enum map with the specified key type."_

Comment:  TIL `EnumMap`. It might be nice to wrap up the enum map constructor to make it possible to instantiate an enum map in Kotlin style as `emptyEnumMap<Enum, Set<String>>()` without the noisy `::class.java`: `inline fun <reified K : Enum<K>, V> emptyEnumMap() = EnumMap<K, V>(K::class.java)`. Personally I find passing a mutable map as the accumulator to `list.fold()` surprising, that's why I just used a for loop: it keeps it clear that the map is being mutated.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip, thanks for the idea, updated my answer! I think `enumMapOf` function name would be more consistent with stdlib, since there are similar functions for `HashMap` and `LinkedHashMap` creation (`hashMapOf` and `linkedMapOf` respectfully), while other `empty*` methods (`emptyArray`, `emptySet`, `emptySequence`, `emptyList`) return immutable data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution that merges the two maps and also merges the inner sets when there are keys in common in the maps:

```kotlin
listOfMaps
    .flatMap { it.entries }
    .groupBy({ it.key }, { it.value })
    .mapValues { it.value.flatten().toSet() }
```

For example:

**Input:**

```kotlin
val listOfMaps = listOf(
    mapOf(
        Enum.First to setOf("one", "two", "three"),
        Enum.Third to setOf("seven", "eight", "nine")
    ),
    mapOf(
        Enum.Second to setOf("four", "five", "six"),
        Enum.Third to setOf("nine", "ten", "eleven")
    )
)
```

**Output:**

```kotlin
mapOf(
    Enum.First to setOf("one", "two", "three"),
    Enum.Second to setOf("four", "five", "six"),
    Enum.Third to setOf("seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven")
)
```